# How to install Xdebug and verify in Ubuntu 14

Tags: ubuntu, phpstorm, xdebug

I have just purchased a new pc, and installed Ubuntu 14. PHP, Apache, MySQL. Everything is running fine but Xdebug  is not working on PhpStorm. Please help me on how to install Xdebug  and integrate it with PhpStorm.

Comment: thanks dinotom for editing... :)

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu 14.04 or 14.10?

Comment: well thank you for ur effort but i already solved this problem yesterday

Comment: You can add an answer to your own question. It may help some other visitors.

Comment: ya sure, i will add an answer for this question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, install XDebug, this assumes you already have a LAMP stack installed with Apache, PHP, MySQL:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-xdebug
```

Now update the options in PHP.INI - /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

## Added for xdebug

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp 
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.max_nesting_level=300
```

Restart Apache2, and you are ready to go!

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Now go to phpstorm -> settings -> Language  & Frameworks -> PHP -> Debug

Make sure the debug port is 9000

now press the start listening for php debug connections button (a phone receiver icon)

enjoy the debugging... :)